# Añadir imagen en la posicion del mouse al hacer click con el boton central

Tags: javascript

Quiro que al hacer click con el boton central del mouse, se coloque una imagen en la posicion actual del cursor.
El problema que tengo es que se coloca la imagen tanto si presiono el boton central como el derecho, y no se coloca en la posicion del puntero, si no que se coloca desfasado

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");

let flag = true;

img.src = "resources/mundo.gif";
img.id = "image";

img.style.position = "relative";
img.style.width = "80px";

let extra = document.createElement("img");
extra.id = "extra";
extra.style.width = "80px";
extra.style.position = "relative";

document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(extra);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let i = document.querySelector("#image");
    setXY(e, i);
});

document.addEventListener("auxclick", function (e) {
    let ext = document.querySelector("#extra");

    ext.src = "resources/" + ((flag) ? "luna" : "sol") + ".gif"
    setXY(e, ext);

    flag = !flag;
});

function setXY(event, element) {
    const x = event.clientX - element.width / 2;
    const y = event.clientY - element.height / 2;

    element.style.left = x + "px";
    element.style.top = y + "px";
}
```

Si alguien me puede aclarar estos 2 puntos se lo agradeceria mucho, un saludo